# JAVA long value printed wrong using logback

Tags: java

I have this simple code:

```
static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(foo.class);
Date dd  = new Date();
Long d = dd.getTime();
LOGGER.debug("{}", d);
```

Prints #-621896692#

What is wrong ?

Comment: have you initialized `dd` ?

Comment: Can you post some kind of [mcve], i.e. versions used etc and how do you know the value printed is incorrect?

Comment: There's a null pointer exception there in dd.getTime()

Comment: @Fernando: No, the code *as written* would give a compile-time error. Presumably `dd` is actually being initialized somewhere, but we have no idea where...

Answer (score -1):

Below is correct code.

```
static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(foo.class);
Date dd = new Date();
Long d = dd.getTime();
LOGGER.debug("{}", d);
```

Comment: The OP is clearly initializing `dd` *somewhere*, but we don't know where. There's no reason to assume they want the current instant in time.